# Trying to identify where is THIS St. John's Way

Tags: google-maps

[image: St. John Way]

I'm trying to identify where is THIS St. John's Way.

Can't find it with Google Maps, too many irrelevant places where showing up.

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to provide more information to enable us to help you.  Where did you get that street view image from? Are you able to access the source?

Comment: Hi,

this picture was shown to me as a part of some kind of riddle which is somehow related to this place.
I haven't trying anyhing but google tools since i'm not familiar with this kind of softwares.

Comment: can you at least give the country? There is at least 19 'St. John's Way' in Canada alone.

Comment: unfortunately this vague information is all I've got.
But I do have reasons to believe it's in USA.

Comment: as shown in the pic, the road should be North to South, hope it will help somehow

Comment: The problem with this sort of question is that it couldn't possibly help any other user, so while it helps you, it's not a good fit to the GIS SE purpose of compiling a list of reference questions with answers.

Comment: my apologies. still, this platform helped me for sure and I thanks 'RomaH' and all of you out there for the readiness to use your knowledge and assist me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is the local name for Wisconsin State Hwy 67 in the township of Old Ashippun, WI

https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/21471927#map=16/43.2250/-88.5173

I am curious of the actual riddle.

edit @mapperz
streetview matching OP
https://www.google.com/maps/@43.2250051,-88.519927,3a,75y,170.22h,76.39t/data=!3m9!1e1!3m7!1slzeMOBi4wPuqhP1v3hhMxg!2e0!7i3328!8i1664!9m2!1b1!2i39

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: how did you find that out?

Comment: I have a database of US highways, the images definitely looked like rural US, so I just did a search by name.  That was really it.

Comment: Ok I thought you were using some sophisticated AI :P

Comment: I strongly believe this matches. In OP's post you can see the cross street begins with an "R" (Roosevelt Road). Additionally, the geometry of Center St, Lorenz Dr, Deer Run Dr, and Fox Run Ln all match. I went to those coordinates in Google Maps and took [this screen shot that looks remarkably similar to OP's image](https://i.imgur.com/fXD0f1J.png) :)

Comment: so here then https://www.google.ca/maps/@43.2250051,-88.519927,3a,75y,170.22h,76.39t/data=!3m9!1e1!3m7!1slzeMOBi4wPuqhP1v3hhMxg!2e0!7i3328!8i1664!9m2!1b1!2i39

Comment: @RomaH edited your question (as you found it correctly) added the live link that shows the street, well-done

Comment: my friend, that was absolutely correct and helpful!
Thank you for this quick and sharp identification.

The actual riddle was given by my molecular biology's professor and was related somehow to the process of DNA transcription.
In this town (which you had found for me), about 100 ft south to this crossing in the picture, there is a small motel called "Pribnow maple inc.".
Pribnow (or more correctly, 'Pribnow Box') is the common name of the a special 6 bases segment on the DNA of bacteria that function as a binding site for RNA polymarese (enzeyme responsible to the transcription process.